# Looking for a powershell script to retrieve the LATEST backup file from an AWS bucket and transfer it to an EC2 instance

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scripting

I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out a way to do this. In bash, I can use AWK to do this--I haven't found a way to do this in powershell though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are AWS Tools for PowerShell that can retrieve data from Amazon S3. See:

- [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/powershell/)
- [Get-S3Object Cmdlet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-S3Object.html)

Comment: Thank you. I am attempting to use Get-S3Object to parse what I need and assign it to a variable. No luck yet (mostly due to my limited experience), but I will keep trying.

Comment: Download it, then open it like a normal file?

Answer (score 1):

Get your credentials stored in some variable.
Store the bucketname in $bucketname.
The script would be:

```
$objects = (Get-S3Object -BucketName $bucketname).key | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1
             Write-Host $objects
```

Pipelining allows you to get the name of the latest file from the bucket. You can apply further filters for file extension (Backup file).